# select returns wrong id when using max

Tags: mysql, sql, max

Assuming a table like this.

```
id town_id begin_date

12 2       2011-10-10
23 2       2011-11-10 
43 2       2012-01-01
```

now if I do

```
SELECT id, MAX(begin_date) AS mx
FROM regions
```

The above query returns the max date but the id is wrong:

```
id mx
12 2012-01-01
```

Is this expected?
How can I get it to return the correct id (43, 2012-01-01)

Comment: Your query is returning exactly what you asked it to return: whatever `ID` it happens to want to choose (since there's no `ORDER BY` or other criteria specified for the `ID`), followed by the highest value in the `begin_date` column.

Comment: What should happen if two towns have the same date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT id, MAX(begin_date) AS mx
FROM regions
GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: +1, But please don't encourage `GROUP BY <columnnumber>` syntax. :) It makes it really hard to read or maintain later when the query gets other columns added to the `SELECT` statement, or a `JOIN` or something else becomes involved. It's much clearer (and nicer for the next person to come along who has to work with the code) to specify the column name in the `GROUP BY` instead. :)

Comment: Maybe you want `SELECT town, MAX(begin_date) ...`?

Comment: @Bohemian The final solution you posted in the comments would only work per `town_id` but not for a single absolute maximum. Also the answer itself is wrong because it returns multiple rows grouped by id which wasn't asked for. I found this question because I had a misconception with `MAX` myself!

Answer (score 4):

If what you are trying to do is get the id associated with the MAX() date, then you can do:

```
SELECT id, begin_date from regions order by begin_date DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I also want to add another possible solution to this answer which might be more intuitive because the accepted answer actually is wrong and only the comment below solves it partly. Why? Because it only works if you want a grouped result by `town_id`. If you you need a solution which retrieves the row with the absolute maximum date you can only go with Francisco Sotos answer or the query below.

```
SELECT ID, begin_date from regions WHERE begin_date = (SELECT MAX(begin_date) FROM regions)
```

The query I posted does not use `limit` but instead requires a sub query. IDK which one is faster but just as an additional food for thought.